# Why does this question not appear when I am not logged in?

Tags: support

I accidentally noted that [a particular question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/why-are-cs-researchers-reluctant-to-share-code-and-what-techniques-can-i-use-to) does not appear on the list of questions when I am not signed in. The question comes up in the top five once I am logged in. Why is this so?

Is it a bug in the feature?

[image: List_questions]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Charles notes, the list of questions on [the homepage](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) is altered for anonymous users: instead of listing recently-modified posts, it attempts to pick questions that may provide a good example of what the site's about.

Currently, that means it's very similar to the [monthly hot questions list](https://academia.stackexchange.com/?tab=month).

If you want to view a list of recently-modified questions without logging in, you can find it [in the active questions list](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=active).

Answer (score 2):

The ordering of questions when unlogged seems to be quite different from that observed when logged in. I can observe the behaviour you're mentioning with other questions, so it doesn't seem to be specific to that question.